# Mongodb, find all latest mapping records only

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb collections with around 2000 millions data represents mobile devices. I will generate a device id when it rigister to my server, for some reasons, it may register multiple times, some there may be  more than one deviceId for one device(imei)

The generate id is the collection id so it is unique.
the collection is like

```
id  | imei  | createTime
```

Now I need to query all device mappings from this collection, but for the same imei, I need the latest device id.

In SQL I may write

```
select id, imei from table join ( select max(createTime), imei from table group by imei) as t2 on(imei, createTime).
```

Is there a faster way in mongodb query?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish grouping in mongo you can either use the older [group by](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/) or the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)